# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6: Show all metrics with one request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

With Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 and the new actuator metrics endpoint, when I request

`GET /application/metrics`

the only the names of the metrics are shown

```
{
  "names" : [ "data.source.active.connections", "jvm.buffer.memory.used", "jvm.memory.used", "jvm.buffer.count", "logback.events", "process.uptime", "jvm.memory.committed", "data.source.max.connections", "http.server.requests", "system.load.average.1m", "jvm.buffer.total.capacity", "jvm.memory.max", "process.start.time", "cpu", "data.source.min.connections" ]
}
```

Clearly I can access a specific metric using 
`GET /application/metrics/jvm.memory.used`

But is there a way to see all metrics with one request?

Answer (score 1):

That's how the `metrics` endpoint behaves in the Spring Boot 2.0.0M* releases. There are only two read operations defined in the [endpoint class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/MetricsEndpoint.java):

- `ListNamesResponse listNames()`

  - Resolves to `GET /application/metrics`
- `MetricResponse metric(@Selector String requiredMetricName,
  @Nullable List<String> tag)`

  - Resolves to `GET /application/metrics/jvm.memory.used`

Metrics support has changed quite dramatically in 2.x (now backed by [Micrometer](http://micrometer.io/)) and the [Spring Boot 2.x upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) is lacking any details on metrics at the moment but it's a work in progress, so presumably more details will arive as Spring Boot 2.0 gets closer to a GA release.

I suspect the move from hierarchical metrics to dimensional metrics resulted in the maintainers deeming the 1.x (hierarchical) metrics display to be no longer viable/suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 2 has removed this functionality by default, but if this is requirement of your application then this custom implementation will serve your purpose: https://github.com/csankhala/spring-metrics-grabber

**Add dependency in you application from local repository**

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-metrics-grabber:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT");
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator");
```

**Add MetricxEndpoint.class to @SpringBootApplication scan path**

```
import org.springframework.metricx.controller.MetricxEndpoint;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = { MetricxEndpoint.class, YourSpringBootApplication.class })
public class YourSpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(YourSpringBootApplication.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

**All Metrics will be published on '/metricx' endpoint with name and value both**

**Pattern search is also supported e.g. '/metricx/jvm.*'**

Comment: So you pretty much created a project pretending to be an official spring-boot starter to circumvent spring-boot's built-in restriction of sensitive data?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas what sensitive data you talking about?

Comment: The metrics exposed by spring-boot. They didn't hide them by default for laughs ... [they hid them because they exposed architectural, structural, and implementaiton details which should not have been publicly exposed in an unauthenticated fashion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas and what structural implementation is exposed by my custom implementation.

I have suggested a way to implement if it was his requirement. it will be his conscious choice whether to implement or not. I hope you agree on this.